# PHP - How to send textarea value with JavaScript AJAX and output it as .txt file for browser to download?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have a textarea, text input and a button wich sends textarea and text input values (using AJAX post method) to PHP site. Now, I want PHP to output textarea value as .txt file so that it can be download via browser.

My PHP code looks like this:

```
$text=trim($_POST['text']);  // textarea value
$fileName=$_POST['fileName'].".txt";  // text input value
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
header("Content-Length: ".mb_strlen($text));
print($text);
```

Nothing happens, so can you help me please. Thanks. :)

Comment: When you say nothing, is nothing happening or is there some sort of error? Check your network log for a 500 or response.

Comment: You can't download a file with Ajax. You can open a new window to point to the file download or send your data to an iframe to call the file generation code.

Comment: Your code works for me. Is this the first item in you php page?

Comment: @DylanMadisetti no error or anything else, just nothing.

Comment: @Robbert actual file.txt does not exist, it's generated on the fly as user sends the data, how can i point it to new window?

Comment: Send it to the page that contains the php code in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered not sending the text to the server and just creating a download client-side?

This post has some useful suggestions you could try to create a download by bypassing the server completely [Create a file in memory for user to download, not through server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665115/create-a-file-in-memory-for-user-to-download-not-through-server)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should clean the buffer

```
while (@ob_end_clean());
ob_start();

header("Content-Type: text/plain");
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$fileName.'"');
header("Content-Length: ".mb_strlen($text));
print($text);

ob_end_flush();
exit();
```